# Mongodb React node express POST request falure

Tags: mongodb, api, express, reactjs

I am trying to pull a post request from a react front-end using Jquery Ajax calls. Yet anything I try in regards to app.post nothing seems to actually send data to the data base. If anything I just get an empty {} on "completed send"

Code: 
Server.js

```
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var gender = req.body.gender;
users.findOne({ users : users.name }, function(err, users) {
if (err) return next(err);
users.save(function(err) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  res.send({ message: users.name + ' has been added' });
});
 });
});
```

Code: 
models/model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    first: String,
    last: String
},
    email: String,
    gender: String,
    school: String,
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Code:

React Actions file: 
app/action/userAction.js

```
class AddCharacterActions {
constructor() {
this.generateActions(
  'addCharacterSuccess',
  'addCharacterFail',
  'updateName',
  'updateGender',
  'invalidName',
  'invalidGender'
);
}

addCharacter(name, gender) {
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/api/users',
  data: { name: name, gender: gender }
})
  .done((data) => {
    this.actions.addCharacterSuccess(data.message);
  })
  .fail((jqXhr) => {
    this.actions.addCharacterFail(jqXhr.responseJSON.message);
  });
  }
 }

export default alt.createActions(AddCharacterActions);
```

React Controller:

app/controllers/userController.js

```
class AddCharacter extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = AddCharacterStore.getState();
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
AddCharacterStore.listen(this.onChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
AddCharacterStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
}

onChange(state) {
this.setState(state);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var name = this.state.name.trim();
var gender = this.state.gender;

if (!name) {
  AddCharacterActions.invalidName();
  this.refs.nameTextField.getDOMNode().focus();
}

if (!gender) {
  AddCharacterActions.invalidGender();
}

if (name && gender) {
  AddCharacterActions.addCharacter(name, gender);
}
}
```

I can't seem to figure out where my error is occurring although I have a sneaking suspicion that its due to my server.js app.post file. Thank you

Comment: Where is your server (server.js) running, what is the exact error you get and where is the error triggered?

Comment: server.js running on root and I'm not getting an error, I get status 200 on the console and a "success" reading on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not defining users in your Server.js. Unless defined outside of the code you posted, your `users.name` is undefined.
`users.findOne({ users : users.name },...` should be `users.findOne({users: name}, ...`